# ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource when accessing temp folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

my application that I have created using ASP.NET and C# uses a temporary path to store a document whilst it is read, and then deletes it after:

```
string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));

Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))), File.Delete);
```

Thankyou for any help. The StockControl document is an example and could be imported from multiple computers on a network. based on the error message it looks like my file is not being uploaded and saved into the temp directory...

local path when debugging (WORKS):

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\temp
```

the application is successfully deployed however when i attach the file and press "Import", i get displayed an error message:
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockControl\temp\Book1.xls' is denied.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockControl\temp\Book1.xls' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Do exactly what error messages says: add <customErrors mode="off"/> to your web.config

Comment: The error says access to path is denied. It couldn't get any more obvious than that :) make sure your Application Pool identity has access to the entire root folder of your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a really simple fix to solve my issue, in IIS I had to right click on Application Pools and set .NET Framework V4 to Integrated rather than classic/

Another solution was to set the specific folder that was being accessed to read/write to the users that required it, this can be done by unique users or within an organization, a group of users

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue.

Made the following changes to fix the issue.

(1) I have gone to wwwroot folder. Right-click and security tab. Provided **IISUSER** to set read and write permission to the wwwroot folder.

(2) Changed the application pool to the separate pool and set identity to Application pool Identity.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Application Pool identity to the local system worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit (x64), create this folder:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

For 32-bit (x86), create this folder:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop