# What identity does iis 8.5 run under?

Tags: iis-8

Its on win server 2012 R2 and researching says its IUSR_MACHINENAME which doesn't even come up when I try to add that to the folder's security list.

The error i'm getting is Access to the path denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis Read it through if you didn't have a chance to use IIS 5 or 6 in the past. I wrote some hints in https://halfblood.pro/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0

Comment: Are you getting this error when accessing a folder on the web? Could you provide more detailed error information?

Answer (score 0):

About the access error you mentioned, you can try this:

> Make specific folders being accessed read/write for users who need it,
> this can be done by a unique user or a group of users within an
> organization. ex: right click and security tab, give IIS_IUSRS setting
> read and write permissions on the folder. Or another way is that set
> .Net Framework V4 in "Application Pool" to "Integrated" instead of
> "Classic".

You can refer to this thread for the similar issue: [ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource when accessing temp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783183/asp-net-is-not-authorized-to-access-the-requested-resource-when-accessing-temp-f)